# Is there a way to get access to the camera buffer in Bevy?

Tags: bevy

I would like to get access to the camera buffer and pipe and that out to a machine learning application, but am having trouble figuring it out. Apparently `camera_node.rs` and particularly `camera_node_system` contain the buffer, but how would I get access to this in a different system?  Sorry I am new to Bevy, so not sure if I could just pipe this out to an intermediate variable and re-use that, or if this is basically impossible in the Bevy framework.

I suppose I could co-opt the `camera_node_system` and put the code I need in there but that is neither elegant nor scales well.

Comment: Not sure of the answer here, but I'm after the same goal, and will share with you what I can find out.

Answer (score 0):

Please take this with a grain of salt, as I too am very new to Bevy, but I suspect this is enabled by way of a [recent commit entitled "Add support for reading from mapped buffers"](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/commit/0a39c81be6b5712c24a75a7c215dbe254097adff)

I am still working my way through this, and will  add to this answer as I learn more. Meanwhile, please feel free to add to, or supplant altogether this incomplete answer.